# Is $(\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{2}],+,\cdot)$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is $(\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt{2}],+,\cdot)$ a field?

---

I know it's closed under multiplication but it's not enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there an $x$ such that $2x = 1$ in your ring?

Comment: What are the invertibles of this set ?

Comment: every $n+\sqrt{2}m$ should have multiplicatively inverse

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. Nice question, and it is good that you wrote down some of your thoughts. As to an answer, it is enough to give a single example of an element in this set that does not have a multiplicative inverse - see the comment by @Arthur.

Comment: ok, so it's not a field. can i just give an example or i need to prove that it's not?

Comment: @HansEngler - you read my mind. thank you.

Comment: @mila You only need a contradiction to show that it is not a field

Comment: @mila "can i just give an example or i need to prove that it's not?" A counterexample _is_ a proof. In order for something to be a field, there are certain criteria that need to be met. Just demonstrating that one of them fails is enough.

Comment: I didn't fully understand the example here. how can u show that $2$ belongs to that structure by $0.5$ isn't?

Comment: If your definition of this ring is the subring of $\,\Bbb R\,$ of reals of the form $\, a+b\sqrt 2\, $ for $\,a,b\,$ integers then you need only *prove* that $\,1/2\,$ cannot be expressed in that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is only a ring.

$2$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ but it is not invertible, insofar as $\frac{1}{2} \notin \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

However, $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a field, and more generally if $\alpha$ is a complex algebraic number so is $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$.

Hope it clarifies your doubts.

Comment: but $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]={a+b\sqrt{2}}$, $a$ and $b$ are integers.

Comment: exactly and you may not write $\frac{1}{2}$ in this form

Comment: and how do u write $2$ in that form?, sorry i'm new at this.

Comment: Make a = 2 and b = 0.

Comment: but zero isn't an integer

Comment: @mila: What do you mean by "zero isn't an integer"???

Answer (score 0):

[Too long to be a comment and served as a complement.]

As all the comments and answer above have already pointed out, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a field *because* $1/2\not\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$.

You could/should do the following as exercises if you don't know why they are not immediately true:

- (a)  $1/2\not\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$;
- (b) $1/2\not\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ *implies* that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is not a field.

---

For (a), suppose $1/2=a+b\sqrt{2}$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, what contradiction do you get?

Answer (score 0):

On can show, rather easily, that an element $x+y\sqrt2$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z[\sqrt2]$ if and only its its *norm* $\;x^2-2y^2$ is a unit in $\mathbf Z$, i.e. if and only if
$$x^2-2y^2=\pm 1.$$